# why does pre-push hook doesn't work with eclipse and works in git bash?

Tags: eclipse, git, githooks

The pre-push  tag doesn't work when I push through eclipse but it works fine when I push through git bash.
the pre-commit tag works fine.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: nope i dont get any error messages , it just ignores the pre-push hook